# bash shell deletes upper-case file names even when pattern is lower-case

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I just entered a rm command with a lower-case pattern, expecting that it would delete only the matching lower-case files, but discovered that also some upper-case files were deleted:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..
$ touch X # note: upper-case X
$ rm [x]
rm: cannot lstat `[x]': No such file or directory
$ rm [x-z]
rm: remove regular empty file `X'? y
$ ls -a
.  ..
```

I tried this on three different Linuxes with identical results. Is this the intended behavior? I thought that Linux is strictly case-sensitive, as opposed to Windows for example. In addition I am surprised that [x-z] selects upper-case characters, but [x] does not.

Comment: It would appear that `X`(upper) comes after `x`(lower) in the range, for example try `[w-x]`(won't match) and `[x-y]` and `[X-y]`(matches)

Comment: This is true indeed! LC_COLLATE also influences range expressions - described in the `glob` man page or [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), in the section *Character classes and internationalization*. @nn41: If you do a `export LC_COLLATE=C`, does this effect still occur?

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to `nocaseglob` turned on.

Check with this command:

```
shopt nocaseglob
```

To turn it off use:

```
shopt -u nocaseglob
```

To turn it on:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

When it is turned on:

```
shopt -s nullglon
shopt -s nocaseglob
touch X
echo [x-z]
# finds the file with uppercase X
X
```

When it is turned off:

```
shopt -u nocaseglob
echo [x-z]
# nothing here
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your locale? Setting locale can influence how characters are ordered.

```
$ touch X
$ LC_ALL=C
$ ls [a-z]
ls: cannot access '[a-z]': No such file or directory
$ LC_ALL=cs_CZ
$ ls [a-z]
X
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set the `nocasematch` option in your bash? Have a look with

```
shopt -p nocasematch
```

If the response says *shopt -s nocasematch*, it means that this option is set. If it says *shopt -u nocasematch*, it means that this option is not set.